# Accessing native Camera, Audio and Files for hosted PWA webapp using Cordova

Tags: cordova, audio, camera, media, hybrid

## Context

I'm working in an [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) application. The webapp is mostly done. It has camera, video and audio record capabilities in browsers using [MediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices) API. When testing this application using Chrome or Firefox both in desktop and mobile devices like Android, all works fine.

However, according [to the browse's compatibility tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices#Browser_compatibility), this feature is supported by few browsers.

With this restriction, I was assigned to develop an hybrid app that uses native phone resources.

## Constraints

- Build a hybrid app
- Web resources pointed to host (files cannot be local)
- Media resources: take photo, record audio and video, upload files
- Support to AngularJS

Answer (score 6):

## Cordova

Being web developers, use Cordova was the natural choice.

I've decided to document this processing because took me a week to get all working.

---

### Steps

#### Summary

1. Open hosted app without local cache
2. Accessing plugins in a hosted application
3. Dealing with files; from device to webview

---

#### 1) Open hosted app without local cache

In order to the application point to the webapp, one can simple change the `config.xml`:

```
<content src="http://YOUR-DOMAIN/index.html" />
```

But that way, when the application loads, it caches all pages into the device. If we change something in the webapp, it does not change in the device, only if we clear the app cache.

To get around this first problem, we used the `com.tiltshiftfocus.cordova.plugin.clearCache` plugin.

- 1) Install the plugin:

In bash:

```
cordova plugin add com.tiltshiftfocus.cordova.plugin.clearCache
```

- 2) Create a simple `script.js`:

Script:

```
var URL = "http://YOUR-DOMAIN/index.html?platform="
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        var targetUrl = URL + cordova.platformId;
        function cb(){
            window.location.replace(targetUrl);
        }
        window.cache.clear(cb, cb);
    }
};
app.initialize();
```

**Note** that we are passing `platform` variable into the main URL. We will use this variable later in the webapp.

- 3) Create simple `index.html` to load a the `script.js`:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: cdvfile: http://YOUR-DOMAIN/ https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <title>TITLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

- 4) Update `config.xml` to point to `index.html`:

Config.xml:

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

---

#### 2) Accessing plugins in a hosted application

The problem of using hosted webapps is that we cannot simple access plugins installed packed in the app. Luckily the solution is simple.

After install all plugins that you want to use, in your Cordova project, navigate to the platform folder and copy all content to your webapp project.

**Android**

Copy the content of

```
Cordova_Project_Folder/platforms/android/platform_www
```

To your `public` directory inside the webapp project

```
Webapp_Project_Folder/public_www/android/
```

**Webapp**

After copy the plugin folder, you need to reference the `cordova.js`.

Webapp Index.html:

```
<script scr="/android/cordova.js"></script>
```

**Note** that we need to reference the right folder for the right platform. Then, in this step, we use the `platform` variable that was previous supplied to the hosted webapp. I'll not go into details of this process.

---

#### 3) Dealing with files; from device to webview

So far we got the hosted webapp and the needed plugins working. Now we need to handle files stored in the device.

To get this process working we've end up using this steps:

1. Get full URL of the file.
2. Convert full URL to `cdvfile://`.
3. Use `cdvfile://` in the webapp.
4. Convert any URL to `Blob`.

**1) Get full URL of the file.**

Pretty much any plugin available that creates or read files (camera, audio, etc) returns the full URL.

**2. Convert full URL to `cdvfile://`.**

The camera plugin `cordova-plugin-media-capture` returns a [MediaFile](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture#mediafile) object that already contains `cdvfile://` path: `fullPath` attribute.

But in some cases, you have to convert the full path e.g. `file:///Pictures/image.jpg` to `cdvfile://localhost/image.jpg`.
You can achieve this using `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` method from `cordova-plugin-file`.

Script:

```
function getCDVFromFullURL(fullURL, callback){
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fullURL, gotFile, callback);
    function gotFile(fileEntry) {
        callback(null, fileEntry.toInternalURL());
    }
};
getCDVFromFullURL('file:///Picture/image.jpg', function(err, cdvUrl){
    cdvUrl === 'cdvfile://localhost/image.jpg'; // example!!!
});
```

**3. Use `cdvfile://` in the webapp.**

One of the issues was reference files in webapp tags. The snippet below wasn't working.

```
<img src="cdvfile://path/image.jpg" />
```

In order to work we need to update the `config.xml` with:

```
<access origin="cdvfile://*" />
```

**Note:** If you are using AngularJS, you have to white list the `cdvfile://` protocol:

```
.config(['$compileProvider', function( $compileProvider ){ 
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|blob|cdvfile):|data:image\//);
}]);
```

**4. Convert any URL to `Blob`.**

The entire goal of this endeavor is to send the resource to the server. We need a `Blob` object to append in `FormData`. We can still use `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` for that.

```
function getBlob(anyUrl, callback){
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(anyUrl, gotFile, callback);
    function gotFile(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(readFile);
    }
    function readFile(file){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            callback(null, new Blob([ this.result ], { type: file.type } ));
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
}

getBlob('file:///Picture/image.jpg', function(err, blob){
    // formData.append('imagem', blob, 'iamge name');
}
```

---

## Wrap up

Now we have:

- access to any media from devices
- ability to display any local media in our hosted webapp
- tools to convert this local media and upload then via webapp

Hope this post saves time.

Comment: Much thanks for your help raphael. I have similar problem but i cant follow your steps. You have a scafolding project to show all structure?